# How to connect patient class with doctor class?

Tags: python-3.x

so I'm working on a problem I found online just to practice my python coding skills and I got stuck somewhere along the line. So I was trying to list all the patient name with the one of the class definition called print_list_of_patients. However, I don't know how to link the patient with the attribute so that I could just refer to the name based on the date of their appointment

I tried to combine each patient into tuples, dict but I still couldn't get what I'm looking for. Basically, I was trying to group the patient class so that every time I look at the appointment date, I can access their name and their sickness as well.

```
class Doctor:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

        self.list_of_patient = []
        self.availability = []

    def __str__(self):
        return "Hi, this is Dr. {a}".format(a=self.name)

    def add_patient(self, patient):
        self.list_of_patient.

    def remove_patient(self, patient):
        for dates in self.availability:
            if len(self.list_of_patient) == 0 and self.availability[dates]:
                print("There is no patient left")
            else:
                self.list_of_patient.remove(patient.name)

    def add_days(self, *dates):
        self.availability.append(dates)

    def remove_days(self, *date):
        for num in range(len(self.availability)):
            if date == self.availability:
                self.availability.remove(date)

    def print_list_of_patient(self, date):
        print("Dr. {a} patient's list for {b}:\n".format(a=self.name, b=date))


class Patient:

    def __init__(self, name, sickness, date_of_appointment):
        self.name = name
        self.sickness = sickness

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {a}\n Sickness: {b}\n\n".format(a=self.name, b=self.sickness)


def set_up_appointment(doctor, patient):
    """
    set_up_appointment(doctor, patient, date)
    doctor = variable name (unique ID)
    patient = variable name (unique ID)
    :return:
    """
    doctor.add_patient(patient)


def cancel_an_appointment(doctor, patient):
    """
    cancel_an_appointment(doctor, patient)
    doctor = variable name (unique ID)
    patient = variable name (unique ID)
    :return:
    """
    for names in range(len(doctor.number_of_patient)):
        if patient.name == doctor.number_of_patient[names].name:
            doctor.remove_patient()
```

Comment: Using hospital.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you're actually asking here. But in general, if you have a reference to a `Patient` object, say `p`, you can access its attributes by simply doing `p.name` or `p.sickness`. So you could for example loop on the Dr.'s patients with `for patient in self.list_of_patients:` and then access the fields as I described above

Comment: @Tomerikoo I get what you mean by the p, but lets say I have 2 patient a and b and I assign them as a patient object. now, lets say they both have different appointment date. I want def print_list_of_patient(self, date): to just print the name of the patient on the given date, if that makes sense. Now I'm confused on that part. How can I refer to certain patient's name with specific appointment date and print it through that function?

Comment: well I see that in your `Patient`s `__init__` method you have an unused argument `date_of_appointment`. So, it seems that you could assign to an attribute `self.date = date_of_appointment` and then again in the `Dr.`'s `print_list_of_patient` method you can do something like `if date == p.date`